# Debug UWP Project on tablet that is connected to PC with USB in VS2015

Tags: uwp

I have UWP project in vs2015, is there anyway to debug My UWP project on a tablet that is connected to PC with USB?
I mean Like android studio or eclipse, can I use tablet instead of emulator?

Comment: [This doc on remote debugging](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/hh441469.aspx) is a good start. A direct USB-USB cable is not OK, though, I am using USB-LAN adapters to connect the devices through Ethernet cable.

Comment: Thanks,It worked, I Run my app on the remote machine, how can I see remote machine screen to see my app on it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to debug through a USB cable put you can use the remote debugger to debug the app over the network